# MySQL UPDATE with JOIN on the same table

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I know that this kind of question has been asked several times. The solution is to use the second identical table not directly but as *virtual* table using SELECT. I worked out two such queries with virtual table. One doesn't work (A) and the other (B) does and I don't understand why (A) does not work.

Does anyone has an explanation for this?

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
id INT
, valid_from DATE
, valid_to   DATE
);

INSERT INTO TABLE tab (id,valid_from, valid_to)
VALUES
(1,'2000-01-01', NULL)
, (1,'2000-01-06', NULL)
, (1,'2000-01-20', NULL)
, (2,'2000-01-01', NULL)
, (2,'2000-01-10', NULL)
;

-- Case (A)
UPDATE tab a
SET a.valid_to = (SELECT MIN(b.valid_from) - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS valid_to
                  FROM (SELECT b1.it, b1.valid_from   -- virtual table
                        FROM tab b1 
                       ) AS b
              WHERE a.id = b.id
                        AND b.valid_from > a.valid_from
                  )
;
-- Output: "You can't specify target table 'a' for update in FROM clause

-- Case (B)    
UPDATE tab a
INNER JOIN (SELECT b1.id
                   , b1.valid_from
           , (SELECT MIN(b2.valid_from) - INTERVAL 1 DAY -- virtual table
                      FROM tab b2
                      WHERE b1.id = b2.id
                            AND b2.valid_from > b1.valid_from
                     ) AS valid_to
            FROM tab b1
        ) b
ON a.id = b.id
   AND a.valid_from = b.valid_from
SET a.valid_to = b.valid_to
;
```

Result:

```
 
id  valid_from  valid_to   
1   2000-01-01  2000-01-05   
1   2000-01-06  2000-01-19   
1   2000-01-20  \N    
2   2000-01-01  2000-01-09   
2   2000-01-10  \N
```

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL it doesn't support case A syntax. It better to go to case B only.

eg: update set statement  doesn't support sub query.

In  SQL server, oracle etc., it will support case A and Case B syntax.

I think these information is useful to you.

Thank you..

Comment: Thanks for info. But does version (B) not contain a subsquery, too? I suppose you mean that subquery with the same table is not allowed in the SET-part. With another table this would work.